# Can Oracle 12 integrate with Azure Active Directory Managed Service Identities?

Tags: azure-active-directory, oracle12c, azure-managed-identity

I want to increase my usage of managed service identities for azure resources (aka MSI).
This works perfectly within my azure ecosystem of course, but we have this one single oracle on-premise database that uses a simple user+pw credential.

Afaik there is Oracle Identity Federation (OIF) that can integrate with (non-Azure) Active Directory via ADFS.

Is there a way I can use this with Azure AD as well?

Cheers